# Create Audio endpoint device - Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am attempting to create a hardware device that sends data to the windows phone via headphone audio jack.

I have researched this and found that the [Core.Audio api on the msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370793%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) offers what I need however I don't think / cant find this in [the windows phone API's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626516%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Is this available to developers?

Obviously someone has access to this because I have seen some companies use it for credit card processors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio APIs you'd need to do this are not included in the standard Windows Phone 8 SDK.

Other apps that are using functionality like this must be using other 3rdy party libraries or have [re]written the functionality themselves.

Comment: So I assumed as much. How do you know which 3rd party libraries are authorized to deploy with the phone? Is there a way to tell? I was under the impress that if it didn't come with the SDK you were SOL

Comment: @AMR In terms of 3rd party libraries then you can use whatever is compatible and does break any store rules (i.e. trying to use restricted APIs)

Comment: and there in lies the problem. If all I am getting is a DLL how do I know if it's breaking any certification policies? Anyway, I will give it a shot. I bet with a little research I could probably weed out most violators

Comment: @AMR You just need to look for a library that claims Windows Phone support.

Comment: I think I am going to have to roll my own. I am looking at a CPP library right now that opens up IAudioClient. So now I know I can receive data over audio jack and stream it. Now I just need to learn how to serialize data into audio and deserialize it back